# Backup (SeBackupPrivilege) and restore privilege(SerestorePrivilege).for domain user

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, file-permissions, server-message-block

How do I verify the if the domain user has backup (SeBackupPrivilege) and restore privilege(SerestorePrivilege)? I tried added the domain user to backup operators group. But  Whoami /priv command output shows that the domain user doesn't have the backup and restore privilege.

Comment: They need to be in the local Backup Operators group, and log off and log back on.

Comment: They are in backup operators group. I did log off and log in again .. But whoami /priv command shows SeBackupPrivilege and SerestorePrivilege are disabled

Comment: Disabled is the expected behavior. Applications that use those privileges enable them in code.

Comment: How do i verify whether the particular user has the backup and restore right?

Comment: By backing up files and restoring files. All backup applications are aware of these privileges and the need to enable them. Also Robocopy can use backup and restore privileges.